# Specifying an expiration date/time when creating a JWT

Tags: community, oauth2, jwt, accesstoken

I have a connected app that I would like to connect to using a JWT flow using a bearer token.

Using anonymous Apex I have:

```
// The consumer key for a connected app of mine
String iss = '<MY CONSUMER KEY>';
String aud = 'https://test.salesforce.com';
String sub = 'my_user_name';
Long exp = DateTime.now().addMinutes(5).getTime();


Auth.JWT jwt = new Auth.JWT();
jwt.setAud(aud);
jwt.setIss(iss);
jwt.setSub(sub);
jwt.setValidityLength(Integer.valueof(exp));

// Storing the certificate in Salesforce is a requirement for using the JWS class
// I just created a certificate under 'Certificate and Key Management' and using that below (jini)

Auth.JWS jws = new Auth.JWS(jwt, 'jini');

String tokenEndpoint = 'https://my.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token';
Auth.JWTBearerTokenExchange bearer = new Auth.JWTBearerTokenExchange(tokenEndpoint, jws);
String accessToken = bearer.getAccessToken();
system.debug(accessToken);
```

When I execute it, I get:

```
18:29:26:041 EXCEPTION_THROWN [33]|Auth.JWTBearerTokenExchange.JWTBearerTokenExchangeException: Error 400: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"expired authorization code"}
```

My user belongs to one of the pre-authorized profiles for the connected app. I have also added my sandbox url to the remote site settings although that may not be needed.

What am I doing wrong? I think it may be due to the certificate but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a token that expires in 5 seconds from 'now' and by the time it arrives at the destination, it has expired, thus the error message.

When you call `setValidityLength(...)`, you're setting the value of the `exp` (expiration) claim. The format of expiration claim is number of seconds elapsed since epoch. From [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.4)

> **4.1.4.  "exp" (Expiration Time) Claim**
>
> The `"exp"` (expiration time) claim identifies the expiration time on
> or after which the JWT MUST NOT be accepted for processing.  The processing of  the `"exp"` claim requires that the current date/time MUST be before the expiration date/time listed in the `"exp"` claim. Implementers MAY provide for some small leeway, usually no more than a few minutes, to account for clock skew.  Its value MUST be a number containing a NumericDate value.  Use of this claim is OPTIONAL.

> **NumericDate**
>
> A JSON numeric value representing the number of seconds from
> 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z UTC until the specified UTC date/time,
> ignoring leap seconds.  This is equivalent to the IEEE Std 1003.1,
> 2013 Edition [POSIX.1] definition "Seconds Since the Epoch"

`setValidityLength(...)` wants a duration (interval) in seconds. Auth.JWT will then translate the duration to the number of seconds since epoch by adding the duration to the current date/time.

This works:

`jwt.setValidityLength(5*60); // expire 5 minutes from now`

Alternatively, you can skip a call to `setValidityLength(...)` and you'll get a default expiration interval...which happens to be 5 minutes.

Last but not least, if what you're trying to accomplish is a callout from one SF org to another, you don't need JWT. You can use an out of the box Salesforce auth provider and grab the token from that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I did that and now I get Line: 52, Column: 1
Auth.JWTBearerTokenExchange.JWTBearerTokenExchangeException: Error 400: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"invalid assertion"} which i guess is a different problem to chase.

Comment: @kratos Yeah that is likely a cert-related issue.